# How to make a border with an inward angle on text?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble figuring out how to make angled borders on my text elements.  I want it to look like this:
[image: Example of what the border should look lie]

Any ideas?  I have tried using tips from the CSS tricks triangles, but haven't had any luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, see jsfiddle - is this what you asked for?

I made two additional divs `#arrow-r` and `#arrow-inner` for triangle and then aligned text with `vertical-align` so that arrow is in the middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/LfErj/1/